# Word: Applying border through styles affects only paragraphs, not text

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I have created a style for displaying code. I have set a border to it. However, in the border menu, there is only apply to paragraph option and not apply to text. Thus, every time I apply my style on a selected text and NOT in an entire row, the border doesn't apply. I have to manually click the border icon to apply, which defeats the purpose of the style.

As an example of what I want the style to look like, you could just see the `code formatting stack applies`, just with a border around.

Any ideas?

[Here is an image of the window.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdtgj.png) There is no apply to text option.

Comment: Any idea how I might apply a border to all the text with a specific style then?

Comment: Yes, I did read that. However, if I select some characters manually and apply a border it works perfectly fine. Now, I assume if I could select all the text of a certain style, I could do the same and it should work. So, could I select all the text from a specific style?

Comment: Okay, so I did just that and it worked. Not the most clean solution, but whatever.

Comment: Ignore my previous comments. It should be possible. See [Add a border to some text](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-a-border-to-some-text-dc90dbd4-11ec-4859-91b7-a41a38e73cd3)

Comment: Yes, I know about that. But if you read my OP, my problem is that the apply to text option is not present when setting a border to a style. I can only choose apply to paragraph, cause styles are meant to be applied only to paragraphs I guess. Though I did find a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create your style, set its style type (dropdown below the name) to be a character style, instead of a paragraph style.  That then allows you to format the border for the style which is text based not paragraph based.

Comment: This is the correct answer. I somehow missed that cause it is grayed out when trying to modify an already existing style. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Apparently what I am asking is not possible.

So I found a workaround, for anyone interested, by right clicking on my style and selecting all text with that particular style. I then just applied a border to all the selected text and it worked perfectly. Not the cleanest solution, but still works.